# Trying to run this out..no compile error..but it is not running on my device please solve it?

Tags: java, android, html, authentication

This is the java code , as i intend to create a login page.
The code is compiling perfectly. When i used my andriod device to run in it it isnt working at all??
The apk is installing but the GUI is not opening..please solve this error?

```js
package com.example.logindetails;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  Button mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
      .parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
    startActivity(intent);

   }

  });
  mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
      .parse("https://twitter.com/login"));
    startActivity(intent);

   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UserName"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Login with Twitter"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />
    
    

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Not a Member?"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    

</LinearLayout>
```

**Please solve the error??**

Comment: what error? something behaving differently compared to the expected result is not necessarily an error. when saying "error", you'll ask us to look at faultive code, which might not be the case

Comment: Please tell us what the error is .... if you want us to help you solve it.  What happens?  Logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what kind issue you are facing.But in your xml ScrollView should contain only one direct child,like below.

```
<ScrollView
    ...>
    <LinearLayout>
       ....
       <!-- you can have as many Views in here as you want -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yup I removed the Scroll View too...Figured out the problem...its the background color which i had given to top linear layout(i.e .....    android:background="@android:color/primary_text_light"

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in your layout

```
<Scrollview> 
<--- your code --->
</ScrollView>
```

**can have only one child**, your code is having multiple child in it, remove them

or make use of another **linear layout with orientation vertical**

here is your code without scrollview and it is generating a output

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/primary_text_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UserName"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Login with Twitter"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Not a Member?"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
```